# How to read a file part by part in C++?

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, filereader, ifstream

I need to read a large text file (over 10,000 lines).

However, the idea is to read one block of this text file (maybe around 15 lines -varies block by block), process it, then continue reading the next block from where I left off.

What I am doing is I keep track of the line number of where I left off, I process my information, then I have a function that moves the file pointer to the place where I left off and I do the next block and so on...

Below is the function used to skip lines:

```
ifstream& SkipToLine(ifstream& file, unsigned int num) {
    file.seekg(ios::beg);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num; ++i) {
        file.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    return file;
}
```

Then in another function I have something like this:

```
ifstream inputfile;
// Taking care of exceptions here...
inputfile.open(fileOBS);

while (!inputfile.eof()) {

    SkipToLine(inputfile, LineNum);
    getline(inputfile, line);

    // Then a function for reading the block
    // Then a function for processing the block
    // Keeping track of the line number
    LineNum = update;

    // If reached end of block, 
    break;    
}
```

I call this above function in another function to loop through the entire file with a condition that says:

```
while(LineNum < FileLength){
    // call function above

}
```

I find this to be inefficient since if the block is towards the end of the text file, I am basically calling a function to start counting from the first line of the file till I reach a certain block that may almost be at the end of the file.

Is there a way that I can actively keep track of the file pointer of where I left off from?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Just keep one `ifstream` object and pass it from the "top-level" function down to all the lower functions? Then you don't need to worry about keeping track of where you are in the file, it does that for you. You can just call `getline` on it without seeking and you'll read from where you left off last time.

Comment: `istream::tellg()` gets the file position, just as `seekg()` sets it.

Comment: Thank you both. I used both of your hints. Firstly, I created a global ifstream object and passed the reference into the required function. Next, I used seekg() and tellg() to figure out the current position of pointer, manipulate the pointer position a bit back (one line back) and continue from there...